# Spark,When Form is submitted call function

Tags: java, spark-java

Suppose I have form:

```
<form method="POST" action="JAVA-METHOD-NAME(foo)>
  <input type="text" name="foo"/>
  <button type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How would I create a Java function that takes the text in foo and does stuff with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

You can't call Java methods in views, however you can get around this problem.

#### Long answer

Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that views have no knowledge of their relevant Java classes. From Java (i.e the server side), you can pass data to views. And from the views, you can pass data to the server side by using forms and urls.

#### Solution

`POST` to a url and then in the Java code get the data that was `POST`ed.

Your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/example">
   <input type="text" name="foo"/>
   <button type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Your corresponding Java `POST` method:

```
post("/example", (request, response) -> {
     // Get foo then call your Java method
    String foo = request.queryParams("foo");
    someMethod(foo);
}
```

#### Alternative Solution using JavaScript

Use JavaScript to do some processing. Note that any JavaScript will also get  executed on the client along with the views, **so you may have to use the above implementation in some sense anyway**.

```
<form method="POST" action="action="javascript:handleIt()">
    <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo"/>
    <button type="submit"/>
</form>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleIt() {
       var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
       // Now send foo to server side by POSTing to
       // a URL
    }
</script>
```